# Poisitioning frame/composition swt in java

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, composite

How can I set the position of the frame in the window? If I run the program now it shows the frame on the top left corner of the screen(small size). I tried setting the size bigger but still no luck.

```
    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setSize(800, 600);
        shell.setText("E-MAIL");
        shell.setLayout(new FormLayout());


//I want this part to be displayed on the middle of the window screen

        Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NO_BACKGROUND | SWT.EMBEDDED);
        Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);     
        HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
        frame.add(htmlEditor);
}
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
shell.setLayout(null);
```

Add before `frame.add(htmleditor);`:

```
frame.setBounds(x,y,width,height);
```

Change x, y, width, height with numbers to adjust size and position of `frame`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.. Already tried that but still showing on the top left of the screen.. Can you maybe edit the code? maybe I am doing it wrong.. thanks

Comment: Ok, instead of `frame.setBounds(x,y,width,height);` try to use `htmleditor.setBounds(x,y,width,height);` before add html editor to frame.

Comment: Can you give me all the code or the project, so i can run it on my pc and try to fix it? Anyway all the code should be posted, so we can see where/how createContents() is called.

Comment: Hmm its not a project or anything, im just testing some stuff, but anyway how can I send you the project? should I email it to you or?

Comment: Like you want.. by email: marcellodavi98@gmail.com or upload it somewhere (for example mediafire...)

Comment: Ok thanks I sent you the project, I hope you can help me.. thanks

Comment: Sorry but i lost the password of the email :D Send here davimarcello98@gmail.com

Comment: Haha ok sent again to the new one